AR Apps showing Black screen in Unity
I am creating an AR app in Unity3D using AR Foundation and Google ARCore. I set up all the necessary configurations, created the build, and installed it on an Android device. The app runs, but it only shows a black screen. Before launching, it prompted me to install Google Play Services for AR, but when I tried to install it, I discovered that my device isn’t supported.
Does this mean I can't use AR apps with Google ARCore on my device? If so, what are the alternatives? Also, what makes the AR service so specific that a newer device can't run it, while some older devices can?

Android devices are extremely diverse.  Many of the "new"  cheaper devices are generations behind current standards.

The new device i have is more expensive then my old device. Both device are not much expensive.
